# Problemas con asp clasico y IIS

Tags: asp, iis, mssql, windows-server-2012

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en asp clasico que corría sobre window server 2012, con un motor de base de datos sql server 2012, luego se realizó una actualización al sistema operativo, llevandolo a window server 2019 y con el motor de base de datos sql server versión 19, cuando la aplicación estaba en el otro sistema operativo funcionaba muy bien, pero cuando se realizó la actualización empezó a dar fallos, como los siguientes: actualmente cuando se conectan los usuarios la cola de request se va llenando y tarda mucho tiempo en responder, y se van acumulando las demás request, ahora se realizó una configuración en el IIS y en el Recycling el Request Limit se aumentó a 150 pero de vez en cuando saca a los usuarios y los manda al login, he leido en varios lugares que tal vez esto se pueda deber a una incompatibilidad de ASP clasico con windows server 2019, si hay alguien con la experiencia de asp clasico, pregunto si creen que estos problemas se deban a la incompatibilidad, ya que como bien saben, asp clasico es bastante viejo.

Comment: A mi me suena más a errores de configuración en el IIS. Si la documentación dice que es compatible, pues es 99% seguro que lo es. Si tu problema es que se "desloguea" ve que tiempos le estas poniendo a la SESSION o la cookie o al mecanismo que estas usando

Comment: Hola @Yussef gracias por tu comentario. En el nuevo servidor el iis está configurado exactamente igual que en el anterior servidor y el tiempo de la session es el mismo que siempre se ha implementado, todo esto empezó a ocurrir cuando se realizó la actualización, no crees que sea un problema de compatibilidad entonces?.

Comment: No soy experto (este es un sitio de programación), pero si fuera problema de compatibilidad seguro habrían mas problemas que es que desloguee eventualmente a algunos usuario. Aquí https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/general/asp-support-windows dice que ASP clásico es compatible con todos los IIS y la documentación de MS es bastante buena. Además tu mismo has señalado que un cambio de configuración solucionó tu otro problema, lo que me da a entender que es por ahí que tienes que atacar (quizás también cambiar algo de código),

Comment: Tu dices que es la misma configuración, pero es que hay tantas configuraciones que difícilmente uno puede estar seguro, o por otro lado quizás no debiese ser la misma quizás una nueva versión de IIS requiere otras cosas. En cualquier caso, yo soy de la opinión que estos sistemas viejos es mejor ni tocarlos.